# Returning object added in ArrayList

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am trying to figure out how i can add an object to a arraylist and afterwards returning it.
My code is following:

```
        mediaTitleCollection = new ArrayList();

        public BookMedia CreateBookTitle(string title, string subtitle, string edition, string author, string genre, int weight, int units, string isbn, int pages, int chapters)
        {
            mediaTitleCollection.Add(new BookMedia(title, subtitle, edition, author, genre, weight, units, isbn, pages, chapters));
            // Return the object i have just added in mediaTitleCollection  
        }
```

I have tried a few methods and searched for half an hour, cant seem to find a proper solution to my question..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Below answers are correct if you don't have to check whether the item added successfully or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    mediaTitleCollection = new ArrayList();

    public BookMedia CreateBookTitle(string title, string subtitle, string edition, string author, string genre, int weight, int units, string isbn, int pages, int chapters)
    {  
        BookMedia result=new BookMedia(title, subtitle, edition, author, genre, weight, units, isbn, pages, chapters);
        mediaTitleCollection.Add(result);
        // Return the object i have just added in mediaTitleCollection  
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
return mediaTitleCollection[mediaTitleCollection.Count-1];//After adding, it returns the last object(don't need to initialize a local scope variable)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mediaTitleCollection = new ArrayList();

public BookMedia CreateBookTitle(string title, string subtitle, string edition, string author, string genre, int weight, int units, string isbn, int pages, int chapters)
{
     BookMedia book = new BookMedia(title, subtitle, edition, author, genre, weight, units, isbn, pages, chapters);
    mediaTitleCollection.Add(book );

    return book;
            // Return the object i have just added in mediaTitleCollection  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    mediaTitleCollection = new ArrayList();

    public BookMedia CreateBookTitle(string title, string subtitle, string edition, string author, string genre, int weight, int units, string isbn, int pages, int chapters)
    {
        BookMedia bm = new BookMedia(title, subtitle, edition, author, genre, weight, units, isbn, pages, chapters);
        mediaTitleCollection.Add(bm);
        // Return the object i have just added in mediaTitleCollection  
        return bm;
    }
```